# Re-applying for the same company after rejection. Email the prev. recruiter or apply in the website?

Tags: recruitment, applications, hiring

Scenario: You apply for a job, do seemingly well in the hiring process, go all the way to the end, but the stars don't align and another candidate gets the spot.

A few weeks later another position open in the same company (an even better fitting role). Do you re-apply through the website or send an email to the recruiter you were talking to?

Answer (score 5):

There's no right or wrong here, but usually we follow the same route thought which we received the information.

- If the open position was informed by a recruiter, go through them.
- If it's a direct communication from company, or you noticed the job post on company website while following up, apply in their portal.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when applying for jobs, regardless of any prior knowledge or existing relationships, the first step should be to **respect the employer's process.** If an employer has a jobs portal, or all their positions are posted through some specific jobs website (i.e. linkedin or whatever), or the employer uses a specific third party recruiter for their hiring, then you should apply through that channel, no matter what. Besides simply showing that you can understand and respect a process they've put in place, this will prevent your resume from falling through the cracks. A resume in an jobs portal will ultimately be funneled through the hiring process. A resume sent to a person may or may not actually get into the official process (for one thing, what if that person is on vacation?)

Then, as a follow up, if you have a contact at the employer that you have a positive relationship with - such as a recruiter you've spoken to about a different role - reach out to the contact, supply your resume directly, and mention to them that you were happy to have the chance to apply to X position. This way, if they did feel highly of you, they can help push your application along.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are found in various ways, but are offered based on relationships (existing or developing a new one).

If you liked the recruiter and genuinely feel the previous job was a "near miss" but this one is a much better fit, reach out to the recruiter. Having a human advocate is far better than getting lost in an automated processing bin.

Also, a good recruiter can provide more feedback on how to re-write your resume, reinforce what you did well before and help you avoid pitfalls that may have hurt you previously.

If you have a contact within the company (like from HR), that might be better.

If you found the job without the recruiter, there is a credible position to apply via the same route. However, recruiters are paid to be sure that your application is seriously considered... a portal has not such bias in your favor.

Good luck!